# How to store a SyndicationFeed into an XDocument?

Tags: windows, rss, linq-to-xml, syndication-feed

I'm programming a RSS Reader in Windows 8 (in C#) and I'm trying to **pass a SyndicationFeed object into a XDocument**. Does anyone know how to do this?

So far I have this.

```
SyndicationItem currentFeed = new SyndicationItem();

/* ... */

currentFeed = client.RetrieveFeedAsync(uri);
```

Answer (score 0):

You've to parse its members as xml elements

```
var client = new SyndicationClient;
Stream st = await client.RetrieveFeedAsync(“http://example.com/feed.rss”);

using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(st)) {
   string rss = sr.ReadToEnd();
```

}